# Phonegap, don't lose input focus when keyboard close

Tags: android, jquery, ios, cordova, focus

I'm using phonegap for develop a mobile application.

I have a search field (an input) and i use http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/.

So, when i focus my input, the keyboard open, i can write a letter, and my script return (or not) a list of user. (Just like examples on my link)

My problem, when i search something and if i close the keyboard, i lose the input focus, so my list of user is closed.

I need a way to, when i close the keyboard (IOS and Android), keep the focus on my input, and keep the value in this input. I just want to close the keyboard, without other effect..

Ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, i have disabled the .blur event on the code of jquery token input... Easy !